# Brewing beer - Flat unpleasant after taste

Tags: brewing, taste

I finished brewing my first batch ever and when we tried it today for the first time it had a flat and unpleasant after taste which I can only describe as lack of taste.

Description of the brewing. The beer spent 2 weeks in the bottles might that be the reason ? Should it be longer ? What controls the after taste of the beer ?

Comment: Good idea, didn't know there is a homebrew stack exchange. I will definitely use it from now on. Ilk try and provide a detailed account of the brewing process.

Comment: Hard to say without a bit more information. Can you update your question to include some details about the ingredients and processes you used?

Comment: Did you prime the beer with sugar before bottling? Had the fermentation completed?

Answer (score 3):

Did it pssst when you opened the bottle? I leave my bottles one week at ferm temperature, then 3 weeks as cool as possible to help the CO2 get absorbed in to the beer to make it fizzy.